# How to add GET parameter to CSS filename in plugin JCH Optimize (Joomla)

Tags: optimization, plugins, joomla

I cannot find an answer to for several weeks. Perhaps my experience in development is not so great :) One site uses the JCH Optimize plugin and I noticed that after clearing the old memory (caches), the CSS and JS file links do not change, i.e. the names of these files remain old. The problem is that the browser checks the file name and if it has not changed, then the site visitors show the old version of the style file. The question itself, where in the plugin (in which code file) i can add some GET parameters  ?vers = 1.1 so that for the browser it is a new file and it would update the information for users. I will be glad to hear any solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/28993/12352

Answer (score 1):

The names of the combined css and javascript files are keyed from the names of the individual files on the page. Clearing the cache will not cause the plugin to generate a different file name.

As of version 7.0.0, there is an option to generate a different cache key if you want to change the names of the combined file. Update your current version to get that capability.